# How to show the edit form of a page just below the page itself in the frontend?

Tags: 7

Just wondering if is there a way to expose the edit form of a page just below the page itself in the frontend.

Let's say I have the page Services, if you click a the **edit** tab you go to the admin page where you have the fields title and body for this page, here you can change its values and save.

I need to show the edit form (fields title, body and the button save) in the frontpage, just at the bottom of the page.

UPDATE: base in neok's answer: **But I can not use $output var in** `utilities_block_view($delta = '') {`

```
    function utilities_preprocess_page(&$variables, $arg, $delta=0) {

      if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {        
        $nid = arg(1);
        //you need to include node.pages
        module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
        $output = node_page_edit(node_load($nid));

        return $output;
      }
    }


    function utilities_block_info() {    
      $blocks['edit_node_form'] = array(
        // info: The name of the block.
        'info' => t('Edit node Form'),
      );

      return $blocks;
    }


    function utilities_block_view($delta = '') {
      // The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
      switch ($delta) {
        case 'edit_node_form':
          // Create your block content here
          $block['subject'] = t('Edit node Form');
          $block['content'] = $output;
          break;
      }

      return

 $block;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can output edit form of current node with [node_page_edit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_page_edit/7) function. So you can create a block programmatically(show this block only on node pages of your content type - *Services* for example) and output edit form with `node_page_edit`.

```
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) {        
    $nid = arg(1);
    //you need to include node.pages
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

    $output = node_page_edit(node_load($nid));
    return $output;
  }
```

[Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/easy-way-to-create-blocks-programmatically) you can find an example how create block.

Comment: thank neok, so I need to add the code to create the block? Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @chefnelone That would be a separate question, but creating a block in code is very well documented; a quick Google search will get you everything you need

Comment: @Clive Sorry, I didn't made my question clear. I know how to create a block, I just need to know if the code to create the block goes before or after the line: "return $output".

Comment: Instead of `return $output` you'd have something like `$block['content'] = $output;` inside an implementation of `hook_block_view()`. `node_page_edit()` returns a form so that should do the trick nicely

Comment: @neok Do I have to put this code in preprocess page function?

Comment: You should create your own module, and put that code into it.

Comment: @Clive Almost done, but I can't use the $output var in `hook_block_view()` Do I need to make this var Global?

Comment: I just updated my question with my module

Comment: `$block['content'] = $output;` this is wrong, you should do like this `$block['content'] = your_function_which_return_output()`